# Using Parse: Cannot assign value of type 'string' to a value of type 'AnyObject?'

Tags: macos, swift, parse-platform

I'm pretty new to swift and osx.  I create a PFUser in another view controller.  When I segue to this view controller I want to store the textfields in the code below and associate them with the same PFUser.  I am getting an error which reads "cannot assign a value of type 'String' to a value of type 'AnyObject?'.  I have read other answers that have similar problems, but I have not been able to fix my problem with their suggestions.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

```
import Cocoa
import ParseOSX

class stageMain: NSViewController {

var user = PFUser.currentUser()

@IBOutlet weak var jobTitleTextField: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var departmentTextField: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var empIDTextField: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var reportsToTextField: NSTextField!

@IBOutlet weak var yearDatePicker: NSDatePicker!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do view setup here.
}

@IBAction func addEmployeeButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    user["jobTitle"] = self.jobTitleTextField.stringValue
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I just saw you mean NSTextfield... My Answer was for UITextField of iOS, not OSX... I have deleted it... :-)

Comment: Hey Neo, Thanks for replying.